# Search an array in first matrix column with numpy and get next column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Having the following arrays (I understand the first one is call a matrix)

```
ids = np.array([['Peter Parker','Spiderman'],['Ben Reilly','Scarlet Spider'],['Norman Osborn','Green Goblin'],['Bruce Banner','Hulk']])
```

And

```
heroes=np.array(['Spiderman','Scarlet Spider','Capitan America','Iron Man'])
```

I'm able to find the "heroes" values that matches rows in "ids" but I can only print the matches like

```
 print(ids[np.where(ids==(np.row_stack(heroes)))])
```

Which outputs

```
['Spiderman' 'Scarlet Spider']
```

Is it (and how) possible to print them like ?

```
['Peter Parker' 'Ben Reilly']
```

**note**
This is a given exercise, I don't expect other requirements like having the qty of elements on the `heroes` array diff from the # of rows in the `ids` array (this would it break my current code due the use of `row_stack`).

But I noticed that my `where` would not find duplicated values on the `ids` array (like if I have 2 "Spiderman" with diff name and both names appears in the `heroes` array), feel free to extend to this but main question is what I just wrote with no other given restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.argwhere` and indexing to get the names. The inner `[:,0]` gives you the two subarrays containing the names and the outer `[:,0]` gives you the first element (name) from each of the subarrays.

```
ids[np.argwhere(ids==(np.row_stack(heroes)))[:,0]][:, 0]
# array(['Peter Parker', 'Ben Reilly'])
```

Comment: Hi sorry, but I got a similar result by doing `ids[np.where(ids==(np.row_stack(heroes))),1][0]` but I am unable to know if this is somehow equivalent to your answer or I am doing something unnecessary , I will appreciate any thought, thanks again

Comment: @Allende: `np.where` and `np.argwhere` gives different results. For my answer, you should use `np.argwhere`. It generates a 2d matrix of indices whereas `np.where` generates an array of 1-d subarrays